# How to separate CSV delimited data and store the values accordingly?

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I've data in CSV in the pattern

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G

C,F,G,L,K,O,F

a,b,c,d,e,f,g

f,t,s,n,e,K,c

B,F,d,e,t,m,A
```

I want these data to store in the form of:

```
A,B,C,D

B,C,D,E

C,D,E,F

D,E,F,G
.
.
.
```

While I'm trying to do in the below way, I missing one pattern in middle. for ex: `C,D,E,F`

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("studentSheet.csv", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
    List<string> subline = new List<string>();
    string line = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] splitstring = line.Split(';');
        string ft = null;
        int i =0;
        while(i <( splitstring.Length - 3)+1)
        {
            ft = splitstring[i] + "," + splitstring[i+1]
                + "," + splitstring[i+2] +","+ splitstring[i+3];
            subline.Add(ft);
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
    foreach(string s in subline)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `c#-2.0` and `c#-5.0` tags.

Comment: Why are you splitting on ";" instead of ','? Isn't it a CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're ok with reading it all into one big list called `input`, and you don't need it to be amazingly fast, you can just do:

```
List<string> output = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length - 4)
    .Select(i => String.Join(",", input.Skip(i).Take(4)))
    .ToList();
```